# Rename all the files in the directory, increasing part of the filename by 1

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I would like to rename files with particular naming convention

all files are named [letter][letter][6-digit number].txt

**desired rename pattern**

> aa**0067**93.txt - > aa**0068**93.txt

Can anyone help ?

Comment: are all files named like [a-z][a-z]######.txt ?

Comment: @amdixon, yes all files

Comment: @John1024 it was removed within 2h.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**rename.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for fname in $(ls * | grep -E '^([a-zA-Z]){2}([0-9]){6}.txt$');
do
  prefix=${fname:0:2};
  prev_nbr=${fname:2:6};
  curr_nbr=$(expr $prev_nbr + 100);
  new_name=$(printf "%s%06d.txt\n" $prefix $curr_nbr);
  mv "$fname" "$new_name";
done;
```

**output**

```
$ touch aa006793.txt ab006794.txt 
$ ls
aa006793.txt  ab006794.txt  rename.sh
$ ./rename.sh 
$ ls
aa006893.txt  ab006894.txt  rename.sh
```

Comment: amdixon,Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (and `ls *` is really dumb). Also, don't use `$(expr ...)` in a Bash script: the shell has lots or arithmetic capabilities included!

Comment: user has confirmed all files are named in particular way not containing spaces or other characters capable of causing issues for parsing ls output. in this context it is fine to parse ls output

Comment: No it is not fine! look at the command you're using: `ls *`. God!!! you're using `ls *`! and then filtering with `grep`. And `ls *` will break if you have too many files so as to exceed the maximum number of arguments. Moreover, OP says that all files he wants to consider follow this convention, but he didn't say anything about all files in the folder.

Comment: Also, `$(expr ...)` and `$(printf ...)` are dumb in Bash.

Comment: provided you dont break the output - youre welcome to edit it

Comment: Don't worry, if I edit it, I will _fix_ the output, not break it (it's already broken). SO is becoming a strange place…

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own shell scripts for this.

In that perform below steps

1) Prepare list of files in that directories

2) Run loop for every files in that list then process its file's name and incremet its  numbrec value by 1 and then using mv command replace that file.

All the best...